# Cordova: How to navigate to page on success of REST response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using cordova to develop mobile app with ionic framework. I am using $http.post method to send request & receive response in json format. On successful activity i want to navigate to next page. My code is this:

```
.controller('Intro', function($scope, $http, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $state, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup) {
$scope.login = function(user) {
    var userName = user.username;
    var passWord = user.password;
    $ionicLoading.show({
      template: 'Logging in...'
    });

$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

$http.post(base_url + "get/memberLogin.php?username=" + userName + "&password=" + passWord + "&tempKey=XHJJUQWERgfrbbbbokaw1222344", {}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      if (data.alert === 'SUCCESS') {
          $timeout(function() {
              $ionicLoading.show({
                  template: 'Success'
              });
          }, 1600);
          var UserData = data.userdata;
          var Username = UserData.personal_information.first_name + " " + UserData.personal_information.last_name;
          var Email = UserData.username;
          var LastLogin = new Date(UserData.last_visited * 1000);
          $scope.users = [{
              username: Username,
              email: Email,
              location: true,
              id: null,
              avatar: 'img/men.jpg',
              enabled: 'true',
              lastLogin: LastLogin
          }];

          $timeout(function() { // it navigates you to next slide to be shown
              $ionicLoading.hide();
              $state.href('templates/dashboard.html'); // getting problem here.
          }, 2000);

      }
  });
```

Problem is i tried `$state.href('templates/dashboard.html');` but it is not navigating to. even i tried `$state.go('templates/dashboard.html');` & `$state.go('^.dashboard');` as to go with absolute one but still it doesnt work. Which is the working one??

I am not getting any error on console too... where is the problem?

Updated route configuration

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
.state('router', {
  url: "/route",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/side-menu-left.html"
})
.state('router.dashboard', {
  url: "/dashboard",
  abstract: true,
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/dashboard.html"
    }
  }
})
.state('router.dashboard.home', {
  url: "/home",
  views: {
    'home-tab' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
    }
  }
})
 ....so on.....
```

Comment: share your routes configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation is driven by routes.

For e.g., in your case you can configure routes like this :

```
    orderStatusApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
                .state('Dashboard', {
                    url: "/Dashboard",
                    templateUrl: "templates/dashboard.html"
                });
    });
```

Then you can use either $state or $location. For e.g., in this case you can use $location like this :

```
    $location.path('Dashboard');
```

or you may also try

```
$state.transitionTo('Dashboard');
```

For more details on angular route, check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) out, for an alternative and more popular routing plugin, check [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Comment: it is showing me error that TypeError: $state.path is not a function

Comment: You should use $location.path("dashboard");

Comment: well $state.go('dashboard) is working but i can't jump from state intro to state dashboard error showing is Error: Could not resolve 'dashboard' from state 'intro'

Comment: for $ location it is showing $location not function

Comment: inject $location in your controller. it is an angular service, must be injected in controller for usage.

Comment: this is working but not navigating to....& i didnt get any error on it. i have angular-ui-router.js added to it

Comment: let me tell you where the problem occurs: the url at the time of login on address bar is this: http://localhost:90/myProjectMobile/Project/module-based/controlr-1.0/index.html#/intro & the resultant url after successful login i need is: http://localhost:90/myProjectMobile/Project/module-based/controlr-1.0/index.html#/route/dashboard/home. The problem coming everytime is "Could not resolve 'dashboard' from state 'intro'" where intro is controller that cannot find the dashboard...

Comment: i got it actually the state was router.dashboard... thanks for your time